# Is there a way to have dynamic default arguments?

Tags: parameters, d, member-functions, member-variables, default-arguments

I'm trying to make a class where the user can modify member variables to change the default arguments of its member functions.

```
class Class
{
    public int Member;

    public void Method(int Argument = Member)
    {
        // This compiles fine, until I try to actually use
        // the method elsewhere in code!

        // "Error: need 'this' to access member Member"
    }
}
```

My workaround so far has been to use magic numbers, which obviously isn't ideal.

```
public void Method(int Argument = 123)
{
    int RealArgument;

    if (Argument == 123) RealArgument = Member;
    else RealArgument = Argument;
}
```

Is there a better way, or am I stuck with this "hack" solution?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yep, forget about the default argument.

```
class Class
{
    public int Member;

    public void Method(int Argument)
    {
        ...
    }

    public void Method()
    {
        Method(Member);
    }
}
```

No need for trickery here.

Comment: This may be impractical for many arguments, but mixins can help generate the code automatically.

Comment: Using variadic templates and careful naming may allow you to get that effect with only the base function and a single wrapper template.